# image resizing based upon the screen sizes

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, lucee

I am using `cfimage` for image resizing and it is working well. my Question is i want to use the `cfimage` to resize the image based on screen size or i can use function where it should see if the screensize is smaller, use the smaller image else use larger image

some function which i can write once and do anywhere instead of doing it in all pages, i know one thing is server side and other is cf side but what if i send the viewport to the `cfside`, will it help or not

right now its working well but needed the update as to how can i build once and do in all

Comment: May I ask why you need to use cfimage for this? If this is about generating images, rather than displaying them, it's very common to generate a full-size and also a thumbnail. You can use CSS or JS  to decide when to show which.

Comment: Are you thinking of making a new image each and every time a new browser screen size is seen?

Comment: Simply put this can't be done using server-side code whether it's ColdFusion or any other server-side language.  The CF code executes before it's displayed back to the browser, so it has no knowledge of the viewport size of the page it's rendering to.  You will need to do this client-side using a combination JavaScript and/or CSS media queries.  Bootstrap would be perfect for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

The "[adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/)" approach does exactly this. You can find a CFML (Lucee/ColdFusion) implementation at https://github.com/cfsimplicity/AdaptiveImages

Essentially it works as follows:

1. Javascript is used client-side to detect the screen resolution and store it in a cookie
2. URL rewriting is used server-side to pass image handling from the web server to the application server (ColdFusion/Lucee)
3. CF/Lucee uses AdaptiveImages to serve an optimally sized image according to the resolution detected in the cookie
4. AdaptiveImages automatically handles creating and caching the differently sized versions of each image depending on how its configured

Obviously there is a performance overhead but I've found it to be negligible and well worth the benefit in terms of reduced bandwidth.